# Invariance of correlation towards changes in mean and variance

Tags: correlation

In this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605405/) I have read that correlation is "invariant to differences in the mean and variability" (to be more precise, they talk about 1 - corr, which is however equivalent w.r.t. this property). I wonder why that is.
Whereby I know that:

\begin{equation}
\mbox{corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\mbox{cov}(X,Y)}{\mbox{var}(X)^{1/2}\cdot \mbox{var}(Y)^{1/2}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} 
\mbox{cov}(aX+b,cY+d)=ac \cdot \mbox{cov}(X,Y)
\end{equation}

b and d clearly signify changes in the mean values of two vectors (sampled from the respective random variables) - and correlation is visibly invariant toward such changes. However, I would like to understand in how far correlation is also invariant towards changes in variance of X and Y, but a and c
seem to be just multiplicative factors and not the variances of these random variables...or am I wrong?